# Killing process group from Ruby kills my whole computer

Tags: ruby, linux

I have a script (script.sh) that spawns a whole lot of child processes. If I run the script from the shell via ./script.sh, I can kill the whole process tree via

```
kill -- -<PID>
```

where PID is the process ID of the script.sh process (this apparently equals the group ID).

However, if I spawn the script from Ruby via

```
pid = Process.spawn(script.sh)
```

I cannot manage to kill the process tree.

```
Process.kill(9,pid)
```

only kills the parent process. And even worst, the following

```
Process.kill(9,-Process.getpgid(pid))  ### Don't try this line at home
```

terminates my computer. 
Trying to kill the processes via

```
system("kill -- -#{pid}")
```

also fails. 
How am I supposed to kill this process tree from Ruby?

Comment: did you crosscheck the value of pid in your ruby script

Comment: Yes, the pid from Spawn corresponds with the pid I see in ps ax

Comment: I would try to fork a subprocess to run the script in it and kill it's pid like in the [kill example](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process.html#method-c-kill).

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found the solution. Spawning the process as

```
pid = Process.spawn(script.sh, :pgroup => true)
```

makes me able to kill the process group via

```
Process.kill(9,-Process.getpgid(pid))
```

It looks like bash groups processes by default, while Spawn doesn't enable this by default.

Comment: Note that there is a significant side effect of setting `pgroup: true` like this. It means that child processes _will not_ be automatically shut down when stopping your Ruby script with e.g. Ctrl-C. You will have to ensure to kill them manually.