# Spawning processes in a process group from Ruby on CentOS fails

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, centos

I have a script `script.sh` that I want to start and stop from Ruby (Rails 3). The script launches a whole lot of child processes so I start it with

```
pid = Process.spawn(script.sh, :pgroup => true)
```

This way I can kill it and all it's children via

```
Process.kill(9,-Process.getpgid(pid))
```

as explained in [Killing process group from Ruby kills my whole computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027973/killing-process-group-from-ruby-kills-my-whole-computer/45032252#45032252) .

This works fine on Ubuntu, however on CentOS 7 this work anymore. If I check all child processes via

```
ps xao pid,pgid,ppid,cmd
```

I see that in Ubuntu all `pgid`'s in the list are the same, while on CentOS the children inherit the `pid` of their parents as `pgid`, while they should inherit the `pgid` of their parents.

Comment: Can you check the ruby signals list in the console on CentOS7 like "Signal.list"? And match the KILL signal number to your code number 9

Comment: In Signal.list there is "KILL"=>9. Don't know how this would change anything? I added more explanation to the question above.